# Show slide which is selected from Select list

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I am playing with jQuery to create a slide show without using any plugin. I am populating a select list with the alt text of image tag. Now I am trying to select the image from slide show when I select any item from select list. e.g. The slide show is on 1st slide and I select 3rd option then slide show should show 3rd slide. Somehow I am not able to figure out how to do it.

Appreciate your help in achieving this.

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = this.value;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jdp12383/ebXJv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful,

```
$('select').bind('change', function (e) {
    $('#exampleSlider').find('li').hide();
    $('img[alt="'+ $(this).find(":selected").val() + '"]').parent().show();
});
```

Here is a working fiddle,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7r7tM/4/)